# Validate structure of str returned from data via data model

Tags: python, api, validation, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to find the best way to validate the integrity of data I receive back from an api.

For example, I have a data set that matches a model (IContact).

**Data:**

```
{
    'aemBounceBack': False,
    'aemOptOut': False,
    'altEmailAddress': None,
    'alternateCountryCode': None,
    'alternateExtension': None,
    'alternateMaskFormat': None,
    'alternatePhone': None,
    'amaScore': None,
    'birthday': None,
    'businessAddress': {
        'city': None,
        'country': None,
        'latitude': 0.0,
        'line1': None,
        'line2': None,
        'line3': None,
        'longitude': 0.0,
        'postalCode': None,
        'state': None},
    'businessCountryCode': None,
    'businessExtension': None,
    'businessMaskFormat': None,
    'businessPhone': None,
    'company': None,
    'companyID': '',
    'contactType': 'User',
    'created': '2020-03-20T03:36:51+00:00',
    'customFields': {
        'spouse': None,
        'user1': None,
        'user10': None,
        'user2': None,
        'user3': None,
        'user4': None,
        'user5': None,
        'user6': None,
        'user7': None,
        'user8': None,
        'user9': None
    },
    'department': None,
    'edited': '2020-03-26T00:36:12+00:00',
    'editedBy': 'Admin',
    'emailAddress': None,
    'faxCountryCode': None,
    'faxExtension': None,
    'faxMaskFormat': None,
    'faxPhone': None,
    'firstName': '',
    'fullName': 'Admin',
    'homeAddress': {
        'city': None,
        'country': None,
        'latitude': 0.0,
        'line1': None,
        'line2': None,
        'line3': None,
        'longitude': 0.0,
        'postalCode': None,
        'state': None
    },
    'homeCountryCode': None,
    'homeExtension': None,
    'homeMaskFormat': None,
    'homePhone': None,
    'id': '0a7e183d-7e72-4d68-87a3-478bdbbd2356',
    'idStatus': None,
    'importDate': None,
    'isFavorite': 'False',
    'isImported': False,
    'isPrivate': False,
    'isUser': True,
    'jobTitle': None,
    'lastAttempt': None,
    'lastEmail': None,
    'lastLetterSent': None,
    'lastMeeting': None,
    'lastName': 'Admin',
    'lastReach': '2020-03-25T17:30:00+00:00',
    'lastResults': None,
    'latitude': 0.0,
    'longitude': 0.0,
    'messengerID': None,
    'middleName': '',
    'mobileCountryCode': None,
    'mobileExtension': None,
    'mobileMaskFormat': None,
    'mobilePhone': None,
    'namePrefix': '',
    'nameSuffix': '',
    'pagerCountryCode': None,
    'pagerExtension': None,
    'pagerMaskFormat': None,
    'pagerPhone': None,
    'personalEmailAddress': None,
    'recordManager': 'Admin',
    'recordOwner': 'Admin',
    'referredBy': None,
    'salutation': '',
    'website': None
}
```

**Model:**

```
NoneType = type(None)


class IContact:
    id = (NoneType, str)
    idStatus = (NoneType, str)
    isUser = (NoneType, bool)
    company = (NoneType, str)
    department = (NoneType, str)
    companyID = (NoneType, str)
    contactType = (NoneType, str)
    namePrefix = (NoneType, str)
    firstName = (NoneType, str)
    middleName = (NoneType, str)
    lastName = (NoneType, str)
    nameSuffix = (NoneType, str)
    fullName = (NoneType, str)
    isFavorite = (NoneType, str)
    isImported = (NoneType, bool)
    importDate = (NoneType, str)
    isPrivate = (NoneType, bool)
    lastResults = (NoneType, str)
    lastEmail = (NoneType, str)
    lastAttempt = (NoneType, str)
    lastReach = (NoneType, str)
    lastMeeting = (NoneType, str)
    lastLetterSent = (NoneType, str)
    latitude = (NoneType, float)
    longitude = (NoneType, float)
    messengerID = (NoneType, str)
    referredBy = (NoneType, str)
    salutation = (NoneType, str)
    jobTitle = (NoneType, str)
    amaScore = (NoneType, int)
    emailAddress = (NoneType, str)
    altEmailAddress = (NoneType, str)
    personalEmailAddress = (NoneType, str)
    website = (NoneType, str)
    birthday = (NoneType, str)
    businessAddress = (NoneType, dict)
    businessPhone = (NoneType, str)
    businessExtension = (NoneType, str)
    businessCountryCode = (NoneType, int)
    businessMaskFormat = (NoneType, str)
    mobilePhone = (NoneType, str)
    mobileExtension = (NoneType, str)
    mobileCountryCode = (NoneType, int)
    mobileMaskFormat = (NoneType, str)
    faxPhone = (NoneType, str)
    faxExtension = (NoneType, str)
    faxCountryCode = (NoneType, int)
    faxMaskFormat = (NoneType, str)
    homeAddress = (NoneType, dict)
    homePhone = (NoneType, str)
    homeExtension = (NoneType, str)
    homeCountryCode = (NoneType, int)
    homeMaskFormat = (NoneType, str)
    alternatePhone = (NoneType, str)
    alternateExtension = (NoneType, str)
    alternateCountryCode = (NoneType, int)
    alternateMaskFormat = (NoneType, str)
    pagerPhone = (NoneType, str)
    pagerExtension = (NoneType, str)
    pagerCountryCode = (NoneType, int)
    pagerMaskFormat = (NoneType, str)
    aemOptOut = (NoneType, bool)
    aemBounceBack = (NoneType, bool)
    customFields = (NoneType, object)
    created = (NoneType, str)
    edited = (NoneType, str)
    editedBy = (NoneType, str)
    recordOwner = (NoneType, str)
    recordManager = (NoneType, str)
```

In my tests I loop through the keys I receive from the api (json) and confirm they match with the model. I'm using `NoneType` to indicate that the object returned can be `None` as well - not sure if this is a good approach.

```
for k, v in json.items():
    assert isinstance(v, getattr(IContact, k))
```

I'd like to be able to validate the values for keys with strings structured in specific ways, like datetimes (iso format), guids, etc.

**What is the best approach to validate these data structures in Python?** I'm using Python 3.8.2 so I have all the latest features. I briefly looked at https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html but I'm not sure if that is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

from validated_dc import ValidatedDC


@dataclass
class IContact(ValidatedDC):
    id: Optional[str]
    idStatus: Optional[str]
    isUser: Optional[bool]


# Let's say you got a json-string and loaded it into a dictionary
data = {
    'id': '123',
    'idStatus': 'new',
    'isUser': True
}

icontact = IContact(**data)
assert icontact.is_valid()

data = {
    'id': 123,  # <-- Error, not str and not NoneType
    'idStatus': 'new',
    'isUser': True
}

icontact = IContact(**data)

assert not icontact.is_valid()

print(icontact.get_errors())
# {'id': [BasicValidationError(value_repr='123', value_type=<class 'int'>, 
# annotation=<class 'str'>, exception=None), BasicValidationError(
# value_repr='123', value_type=<class 'int'>, annotation=<class 'NoneType'>, 
# exception=None)]}
```

https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc

Answer (score 0):

I think your are looking for [JSONDecoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#json.JSONDecoder) using the `object_hook` parameter to customize the decoding. You can add your validation logic there. This support simple types out of the box. Might get you most of the way there. I would suggest to duck type your result. If it has the data that you need assume that the record is correct.

If it is critical that the record is the correct type then it may be easier to validate the decode python object than the json itself.